# Generating CSV in Rails from crossed Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method `to_csv` which collect the guest_id from a `Booking` table, but instead of returning the `guest_id`, i would like to retrieve the `first_name` and `last_name` as well as the `email` from the `User` table and put each of them in a row in a csv file.
My method looks as follow:

```
def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w[guest_id]
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes
      all.each do |contact|
        csv << attributes.map { |attr| contact.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
```

Does anybody know how i could do this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have the correct one to one `user` relation defined in `Booking`.

```rb
def self.to_csv
  attributes = %w[guest_id first_name last_name email]
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << attributes
    all.includes(:user).each do |booking|
      csv << [booking.guest_id, booking.user.first_name, booking.user.last_name, booking.user.email]
    end
  end
end
```

please note now `guest_id`, `user.first_name`, `user.last_name`, `user.email` are in a row. If you want a different format, you can adjust accordingly.

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you very much, on the booking table unfortunately i do not have the relation defined between the user and the booking. Is there an alternative please ?

Comment: If `booking` and `user` do have some kind of relationship (eg one to one), you should define it in the model. Then you can use all the good things rails provided.

Comment: I understand, but it actually does NOT, and i cannot modify the relationship now. Any other way you would think off please ?

Comment: If they don't have any relationship, how can they fit into one csv row? How do you know which user information should be displayed with which booking?

Comment: I was hoping to do a find_by approach

Comment: `find_by` what attribute?

Comment: email = User.find_by(id: contact.contact.guest_id).email

Comment: so, this is the relationship, `guest_id` is a reference of user `id`, right?

Comment: That is correct. guest_id is can be looked up in User table ids

Comment: So, you can write relations in models. It's rails way to associate records